# steam-launcher cannot connect to network

Tags: wireless, networking, steam

I was downloading Team Fortress 2 via Steam for Ubuntu when the download paused suddenly.
I tried to replug my WLAN stick (TL-WN821N by TP-LINK) but it cannot connect.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why it worked, but I went `Steam > Go Online...` and now it resumes the download. That's weird.

Comment: Confirmed on Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail. After a second launch, Steam cannot connect to the network. Router reset did nothing. Launched in offline mode, and the selected Steam > Go Online. Store is now accessible, and my downloads resume.